# Jquery mobile trigger collapsible not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i'm trying to collapse programatically a collapsible with a simple

JavaScript:

```js
$( ".nuovoPaziente" ).trigger( "collapse" );
```

HTML:

```html
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b" id="nuovoPaziente">
</div>
```

but it doesn't work.
I have the lastest jquery mobile library 1.1.1. I'm sure the execution arrives to the trigger code for i have an alert before checking that it arrive to execute the code.
Any idea? ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used an `ID` in your definition of your collapsible:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b" id="nuovoPaziente">
```

So, it should be `#nuovoPaziente` instead:

```
$( "#nuovoPaziente" ).trigger( "collapse" );
```

---

`.nuovoPaziente` is related to a `class`; so if you want to keep this convention, you will have to modify your collapsible to something like this:

```
$( ".nuovoPaziente" ).trigger( "collapse" );

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b" class="nuovoPaziente">
```

---

The folowing example worked for me:

**JS / jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#collapse").click(function() {
        console.log("ok");
        $( "#nuovoPaziente" ).trigger( "collapse" );
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">

            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b" id="nuovoPaziente">
                <h3>I'm a header</h3>
                <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
            </div>

            <button id="collapse">collapse!</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

I called the libraries as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

You may have a try at the example above.

Hope this helps. Let me know about your results.

Comment: aww... :S I'll try it in my environment mate :). I'll let you know about my results

Comment: Hey mate, I re-edited the last part of my post. Maybe have a try at the example I posted and see it this work for you. Let me know if this works or not :).

Comment: keep not working... can i ask you the way you call the library? This is mine:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Find my library call in the end of my post. Hope this will help you solve your problem. Let me know :)

Comment: I corrected the libraries call, which (shame on me) effectively contained an error (never raised in two months of work :D) and now your example works like a charm singularly, but when i move the example inside the real page in which it is supposed to work, it doesn't do anything. I guess i have some problem of unbalanced tag div or something like. -3- I'll try to guess what's the issue, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: A quick tip before leaving: What you can do is to use your console (Firebug is great!!! :P) to check if you have some issues (like synthax issues or missing libs) with javascript / jQuery. It's very useful ;)

Comment: Firebug? I'll go check! Usually i use the error console by firefox, but i imagine it's the proper tool ^^'

Comment: Wooo! It works! Simply i forgot to delete your example and they were coexisting with the same name and so the second simply didn't work ^^' Finally the real issue was the problem with the library. I'd never get through without your help! Thank you to have saved the day! :D

Comment: Have a try with :D. You'll like it for sure lol ^^. You can install Firebug in Firefox as an additional module :)

Comment: Your welcome, I'm glad this solved your issues ^^. Yiha! We should celebrate this day :D lol

Comment: Installed and it's cool! Thank you! I will ask you to the calendar authority to assign the day a national holiday! lol!

Comment: hahaha!!! :D Yeah, Firebug is really cool and so helpful!!! :D Usually I check Firebug's console when I have js / jquery functions defined to check whether I missed something or not. You can also select HTML elements with your mouse, and check the content of each node ^^. Firebug I love you lol <3<3<3 :D